# WPF C# MVVM UserControl Binding Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, user-controls

I have a usercontrol for each item (ScreenViewItemControl)(works ok), not adding code but can if needed.

I then have a usercontrol to list all item usercontrol (ScreenViewControl) such as:

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Screens}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedScreen}" 
             ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ScreenViewStyle}"
             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
             BorderThickness="0" 
             Background="Transparent">

        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
```

I have a ViewModel (ScreenViewViewModel):

```
    public ObservableCollection<ScreenInfo> Screens { get; set; }

        public ScreenInfo SelectedScreen { get; set; }

        public ScreenViewViewModel()
        {
            Screens = new ObservableCollection<ScreenInfo>
            {
                new ScreenInfo
                {
                    Name = "ScreenSoft 1",
                    Status = "Online",
                    Location = "First Floor",
                    Resolution = "1920x1080",
                },
            };            

         }
```

And I place the control in a page with

```
<local:ScreenViewControl />
```

I can see it is creating the 1 item, but I am guessing I am databinding wrongly? What am I overlooking?

[image]

**Adding ScreenViewItemControl for clarity**

```
    <UserControl.Resources>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="ScreenViewItemTemplate">
            <Border Padding="0 3" 
                    Margin="20 20 0 0" 
                    BorderThickness="2" 
                    BorderBrush="{StaticResource BlueBrush}" 
                    CornerRadius="20" 
                    Height="210" 
                    Width="192"
                    Background="{StaticResource BackgroundWhiteBrush}">

                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0 3">

                    <!-- Device Name -->
                    <TextBlock Width="192" Height="30"
                               TextAlignment="Center"
                               FontWeight="Bold"
                               FontSize="{StaticResource FontSizeXL}"
                               Text="{Binding Name}" />

                    <!-- ScreenShot -->
                    <Image Width="192" Height="108" 
                           Margin="0 6" 
                           Source="{Binding ScreenShot}" />

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >

                        <!-- Device Status -->
                        <TextBlock Height="20" 
                                   Text="{Binding Status}" 
                                   TextAlignment="Center" 
                                   Padding="6 4" />
                        <!-- Device Location -->
                        <TextBlock Height="20" 
                                   Text="{Binding Location}" 
                                   TextAlignment="Center" 
                                   Padding="6 4" />

                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>

    </UserControl.Resources>

<ListBoxItem Style="{StaticResource ScreenViewStyle}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define `ItemTemplate` for this `ListBox`. By default, if you bind a collection of objects to `ListBox` their `ToString()` method is invoked to represent every single object in this list.

Below is an example how you can do that (I have deleted all properties from `ListBox` for brevity).

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>                
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

As Robert pointed on the comment you can also override `ToString()` method in the `ScreenInfo` class. But it depends on what would you like to display to the user. If it is the simple text you can use the overridden `ToString()` method, but if you want to display your item with more fancy way you should use `ItemTemplate`. In `ItemTemplate` you can define how every single property from your class should be displayed to the user.

Comment: You could also write a `ToString()` overload that does the right thing.

Comment: You would obviously somehow have to define how a ScreenInfo item should be displayed. This is usually done by assigning an appropriate DataTemplate to the ItemTemplate property of the ListBox. Overriding the ToString method of the item class is usually a hack and only helps as long as there is no other control that should visualize the item in a different way. In case you only want to show a single property of an item, you may also set the DisplayMemberPath property.

Comment: @Clemens: "SSDS.Lite.ScreenInfo" isn't particularly useful.  ToString has the ability to be overloaded precisely for these kinds of scenarios.  Having a useful overload doesn't hurt anything; you can still use an `ItemTemplate` if you want more control.

Comment: @RobertHarvey What if there are two ContentControls that are supposed to show the same item in different ways? Overriding ToString is a hack. In WPF, we have DataTemplates.

Comment: I have added the itemusercontrol where I define the datatemplate, is this useful?

Comment: @FranckE If you have a UserControl showing the item, you would put that in the DataTemplate: `<ListBox.ItemTemplate><DataTemplate><local:YourUserControl .../></DataTemplate></ListBox.ItemTemplate>` where `...` would optionally be a set of Bindings of the properties of your control, if it does not operate directly on the item type.

Comment: That was exactly what I had overlooked, thanks Clemens and thanks everyone else :)